# method declaration

Tags: java, methods

I haven't been programming for long and this is my first time declaring a method within my program and using this method in the program. In its simplicity, the program has the user enter a 5 digit zipcode and the method I created checks that the zipcode is only 5 characters and is all digits. When I use the method in the program no matter what I enter for the zipcode, the while statement runs asking me to input my zipcode again. This should only happen if you enter a string thats not five characters or a string without only digits. However, right now it is happening even when an actual zipcode is entered, leaving me to assume something is wrong with the method. I tried to be as clear as possible in the question but if any further clarification is needed I can try to clear things up, any info you can give would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String zipcode;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a 5 digit zipcode: ");
        zipcode = in.nextLine();

        while (checkInput(zipcode) == false) {
            System.out.println("You did not enter a 5 digit zipcode: ");
            zipcode = in.nextLine();
        } // end while

    } // ends main

    public static boolean checkInput(String zipcode) {
        boolean zipcodeLength = true;
        boolean zipcodeDigits = true;
        if (zipcode.length() != 5) {
            zipcodeLength = false;
        } // end if statement
        for (int i = 0; i <= zipcode.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(i)) {
                zipcodeDigits = false;
            } // end if statement
        } // end for statement
        if (zipcodeLength == false || zipcodeDigits == false) {
            return false;
        } // end if statement
        else {
            return true;
        } // end else statement
    } // end checkInput
}
```

Comment: FYI your whole checkInput can be replaced by `zipcode.matches("\\d{5}")` Less code, less headache.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug such simple problems yourself.  Even without a debugger you can insert System.out.println calls to find out what's happening in your code.

Comment: @HotLicks +1 An important skill for beginners and experts alike.

Comment: if(!Character.isDigit(i)){
      zipcodeDigits = false;
This portion seems to have problem

Answer (score 5):

This is your problem :

```
if(!Character.isDigit(i))
```

should be

```
if(!Character.isDigit(zipcode.charAt(i)))
```

Comment: a compile error is returned saying CharAt isnt defined for type (int) I appreciate the help im trying to learn Java on my own and dont have anyone to sit down with me and help.

Comment: @user1701604 Also change `i <= zipcode.length()` to `i < zipcode.length()`. Chars are indexed from `0` to `length-1` in Strings, just like in arrays.

Comment: @user1701604 The sooner you learn to master ctrl-space, the better. I hope you are using an IDE to code in Java!

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarCode{ public static void main(String[] args){

    String zipcode;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a 5 digit zipcode: ");
    zipcode = in.nextLine();
    while (checkInput(zipcode)==false){
        System.out.println("You did not enter a 5 digit zipcode: ");
        zipcode = in.nextLine();
    }
}


public static boolean checkInput(String zipcode){
    boolean zipcodeLength = true;
    boolean zipcodeDigits = true;
    if (zipcode.length() != 5){
        zipcodeLength = false;
    } // end if statement
    for (int i=0; i<zipcode.length();i++){
        if(!Character.isDigit(zipcode.charAt(i))){
            zipcodeDigits = false;
        }
    }
    return zipcodeLength && zipcodeDigits;
    } // end checkInput
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not store the boolean value `false` in some boolean variable. Just return the moment you find that the zipcode is invalid.

And you should do : -

```
!Character.isDigit(zipcode.charAt(i))
```

in place of: -

```
!Character.isDigit(i)
```

So, you can modify your method like this: -

```
public static boolean checkInput(String zipcode){

  if (zipcode.length() != 5){
    return false;
  } 

  for ( int i = 0; i < zipcode.length(); i++){
    if(!Character.isDigit(zipcode.charAt(i))){
      return false;
    } 
  } 

  return true;
}
```

Also, you don't need to do :- `booleanVar == false`. Just do : - `!booleanVar` thats enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static boolean checkInput(String zipcode){
      if (zipcode.length() != 5){
        return false;
      } 
      for ( int i=0; i<zipcode.length();i++){
char charAt = zipcode.charAt(i);
        if(!Character.isDigit(charAt)){
          return false;
        } 
      } 
     return true;
    }
```

You needed to use charAt instead of seeing if `i` was a digit, because obviously it will be.

Comment: when i do this an String input out of bounds exception is thrown when i enter my zipcode

Comment: @user1701604 Try that. I forgot to remove the `<=` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

The first is that you're going `<=` when you need to be doing `<`.

The second is that you need to check `zipcode.charAt(i)` instead of `i`. Checking `i` will check the digits 0 - 4 (5 with your code) for a 5 digit zipcode no matter what zipcode you enter.

So those two lines become

```
for ( int i=0; i<zipcode.length();i++){
    if(!Character.isDigit(zipcode.charAt(i))){
```

Alternatively, I personally would code this method like this:

```
public static boolean checkInput(String zipcode){
     if(zipcode.length() != 5) return false; // bad length
     for(int i = 0; i < zipcode.length(); i++) {
         if(!Character.isDigit(zipcode.charAt(i)) // bad digit
             return false;
     }
     return true; // if no bad condition, it's good
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  while (zipcode.matches("[0-9]{5}"))==false){
    System.out.println("You did not enter a 5 digit zipcode: ");
      zipcode = in.nextLine();
  }
```

Comment: Great answer, really. Exactly the same as the first comment below the question and with no clarification at all. Not to mention that OP is here to debug HIS code.

Comment: I wouldn't know, but I presume he/she is a person. OP = Original Poster (term used around public forums; on SO means the owner of the question).

Answer (score 0):

```
!Character.isDigit(i)
```

That looks like a mistake to me. `i` is of type `int`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= zipcode.length(); i++) {
// ...
}
```

So you're not calling [`Character.isDigit(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29), you're calling [`Character.isDigit(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28int%29). The two methods behave differently: one deals with a text characters while the other deals with a numeric unicode value. Try this:

```
System.out.println("= char '1' =");
System.out.println(Character.isDigit('1')); // true

System.out.println("= int 1 =");
System.out.println(Character.isDigit(1)); // false

System.out.println("= Unicode 31h (49) =");
System.out.println(Character.isDigit('\u0031')); // true

System.out.println("= int 49 =");
System.out.println(Character.isDigit(49)); // true
```

And you'll get the following output:

```
= char '1' =
true
= int 1 =
false
= Unicode 31h (49) =
true
= int 49 =
true
```